# Plot Distinct Count by Date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in which dates (YYYY-MM-DD) correspond to ID codes that each correspond to a product. The date determines when a specific customer (given by a customer code) purchased the product. I am trying to plot how many customers bought a given product across time with a line plot.

So far I have converted dates to datetime

`df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')`

Taken the distinct count of the product code in question - this should correlate to the number of people who bought it

`Product_A = df.loc[df['Product_Code'] == 'ABCD'].nunique()[0]`

and attempted to plot Product_A by the date

`plt.plot(df.Dates, Product_A)`

When I try this, I get the error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (28356274,) and (1,)

Clearly I need to somehow ensure that my x and y axis are the same size, but I am unsure how to do this. Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: `print(Product_A)` what do you see? (it's a scalar)

Comment: Right, it gives the total times Product_A shows up in the data. Does it have to be an array? Can I just do ```plt.plot(df.Dates, (np.arrray(Product_A))```

Comment: `df['Dates']` is every date in your dataframe. Where would this one point go in time?

Comment: Here's an exercise I like to do: draw by hand the plot you'd like to see. It tends to lead to a lot of insight about the data preparation process